# iOSのショートカットで「URLの内容を取得」しても画像が表示されない

Tags: ios, safari

今回、自分で設置したWebサーバーにiOSショートカットから接続してPOSTでファイルを送信しようと思っています。その前準備として、ごくごく簡単なHTMLを作りテストしていますが、画像のみが表示されません。

iOSのSafariではきちんと画像が表示されます。ショートカットの「URLの内容を取得」だとうまくいかないようです。

```
test.html
<html>
<body>
<img src=“test.jpg”>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 提示されたソースコードの中の `test.jpg` の両側のダブルクォーテーションは， `ascii: 0x22` ではない文字 `utf-8: 0xE2809C, 0xE2809D` のようです。コピペしたらsafariでもうまく表示できないので気がつきました。

Comment: 恐れ入ります。ダブルクオーテーションとは別の文字ということでしょうか？WindowsからSSH経由でLinuxサーバーをいじっており、Shift + 2で入力していますが、これとは違う文字ということでしょうか？

Comment: ほとんど字形に差がないので気づき難いです。ブラウザ（Safari と Edge で確認）でこのページの `test.jpg` の部分をかなり拡大すると，前後で字形が異なりかつ回答の中の字形（前後で同一）とも異なっていることがわかると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「URLの内容を取得」だと基本HTMLの文字列しか取得できないとおもいます。
HTMLを取得しても端末側にはtest.jpgが存在しないので表示できないんだと思います。

なので、test.jpgを`<img src="http://localhost//test.jpg">`とかにしたらうまくいくかもしれません。